# which linux distribution on my netbook

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, acer, aspire

I have an Acer Aspire One netbook and I want run Linux on it, but I don't know which distribution I should choose. It has a 1.66 GHz Intel Atom processor and about 1 GB RAM, so it shouldn't be too heavy.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available

Comment: If you're interested in considering non-Ubuntu distributions as well, then this might be a better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to consider [Lubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) and [Xubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

I have an Acer Aspire One D257 and have a couple problems, there is a small pause that I only notice when programming [0] and the sound has stopped working in 12.04, but other then that I think Ubuntu is fine, if a little slower than on a full blown Desktop computer or laptop.

If speed is important to you you might want to consider Xfce or Xubuntu which uses Xfce instead of Gnome or Unity by default.

[0] [How to diagnose Ubuntu CPU spikes / IO wait?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116844/how-to-diagnose-ubuntu-cpu-spikes-io-wait)

Answer (score 2):

After trying a number of distros, I have finally settled on LXLE, based on Lubuntu, to run on my Acer Aspire One 722. It works really well if you do this:

1. Set boot order (F2 on boot) with NETWORK boot as first option, USB HDD second and internal HDD third.
2. Boot LXLE from a usb stick use unetbootin to install the ISO in Linux, or Yumi or similar in Windows)
3. Link to your wi-fi and make sure the mouse cursor moves - try moving it around for a minute or so - if it freezes, you need to connect a wired network and re-boot.
4. Start the installation process once you have it booted from live usb.
5. Use the 'advanced' option with gparted to partition your disk, if you are starting from scratch. I set up 4 partitions as follows:

   - a boot partition of 250Mb
   - a root partition of 25Gb
   - a swap partition (at the end) of 8Gb
   - a home partition of the rest (about 260Gb)
6. Finish the install and re-boot, using the ethernet connection if you had a frozen cursor earlier.
7. Go top this page and follow the instructions for power management http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811178 and the rest is useful too.
8. If you have any sound problems, go here - http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/202-ubuntu-acer-ao722

Welcome to a fast and easy to use netbook!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using an Acer AO722 for nearly two years, and I have tested lots of distros. Here are some findings:

- avoid any distro with KDE, for they overload the system. CPU temperature gets very high!
- Unity and Gnome are Ok, everything works fine (as long as you fix the boot order - see above answers), but they consume too much memory.
- XFCE distros work fine, too, with very low memory consume. I've been using Xubuntu 12.4 for more than a year, and it's on top of my GRUB order! The problem with the XFCE distros is the sound issue(s). I've managed to fix it, but I can't remember how (sorry)! It has to do with some lines in the Configuration Editor.
- LXDE distros have no sound at all, and i couldn't find a way to fix it (I've tryed Lubuntu and Peppermint).
- Bodhi Linux is great and works fine, after configuring the workspace.
- Puppy Linux Slako is another great distro. Everything working fine, but wireless configuration can be tricky.

My final choices are Xubuntu and Linux Mint.